# Reboot Redhat Enterprise Linux

Tags: rhel, reboot

How can I reboot the RHEL from CLI using the systemctl method?

Comment: does `systemctl reboot` work?

Answer (score 5):

As root, say

```
# systemctl --reboot
```

Or, simply:

```
# reboot
```

On systems where `systemctl` can reboot the system, `reboot` is [usually symlinked to it](http://echorand.me/2013/11/21/poweroff-halt-reboot-and-systemctl/), so that `systemctl` detects the action to perform by the name it was called by.

If you're on RHEL 7 or newer or you have manually configured `sudo` on RHEL 6 or older, you may not have to log in as `root` or `su` up to `root` first:

```
$ sudo systemctl --reboot
```

Or:

```
$ sudo reboot
```